# Ubuntu v19.10- Tracker is not working

Tags: linux, c

In MAC there is concept of [spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(software)) which is used for indexing.
In linux, gnome file manager is used tracker for file searching and tracker is used for file indexing.
When I have searched for a file in search box, the running process is shown as Nautilus.
I want to ignore the indexing process from my program but i didn't find out the process name for it?
How did I get the process name for indexing process only i.e for Tracker?
What database is used when indexing? and what is the location of it?

Comment: Maybe `pstree -p`? BTW welcome on superuser. You may start to read [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/GettingStarted) doc pages...

Comment: Hi again, welcome on SuperUser. I slightly enhanced the readibility of you post. Feel you free to roll-back the modifications or to [edit] your post adding details. Give a look to [ask] if you already have not done.

Comment: Thank you @Hastur, from next time i will try to post my question in proper way.

Comment: You're welcome. Do not worry about it: new site, interface, rules, best practice, upvote, downvote... and a problem to solve. Only remember that you have clean in your mind your problem,  who reads/is listening you not (yet). BTW you have an answer below. Give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Deamon, indexing and others....

From Tracker [getting started pages](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/GettingStarted)

> <kbd>tracker-store</kbd>  The data store and daemon to interface to Tracker's databases
>
> <kbd>tracker-miner-fs</kbd>  The **file system crawler** to mine data from local files
>
> <kbd>tracker-extract</kbd>   The meta-data extraction application used on each file
>
> <kbd>tracker-writeback</kbd> The application for writing meta-data back to files

#### Then, locations

> The databases are kept in `$HOME/.cache/tracker`.
> The user's data backup is kept in `$HOME/.local/share/tracker/data.`

#### Finally process individuation

If the name of the running program is `tracker-whatever` you can find the ip with  something like

```
ps -aux | grep tracker
```

If `pstree` is installed you can use with the `-p` option to search which processes depend from the already spottend Nautilus one.